# PHP Getting text between HTML nodes

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, regex

Title says all. How can I get the text between HTML nodes using PHP? Any ideas?
Below is my HTML structure.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="first">
            <p class="this">Hello</p>
            <p class="this">Community</p>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            <p class="that">Stack</p>
            <p class="that">Overflow</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Expected output:**

```
HelloStackOverflowCommunity
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser library, like `DOMDocument` or `PHP Simple HTML DOM`.

Comment: It is not good idea to use regexp to parse HTML.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried? If so could you post the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054815/php-domdocument-read-element-inner-text and you might also want to look at strip_tags()

Comment: just play with this: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use PHP inbuilt [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) rather than a third party class like simplehtmldom.

On big HTML files they are really slow (I have worked with them).

```
<?php
$html ='
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="first">
            <p class="this">Hello</p>
            <p class="this">Community</p>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            <p class="that">Stack</p>
            <p class="that">Overflow</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
';

// a new dom object
$dom = new domDocument; 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// load the html into the object
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
// get the body tag
$body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
 // loop through all tags
foreach($body->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element ){
    // print the textValue
    print $element->firstChild->textContent;
}
```

The output would be `HelloCommunity StackOverflow`

Answer (score 1):

That's quite easy, get PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

Then use the following code:

```
/* include simpledom*/
include('simple_html_dom.php');

/* load html string */
$html_string = <<<HTML
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="first">
            <p class="this">Hello</p>
            <p class="this">Community</p>
        </div>
        <div id="second">
            <p class="that">Stack</p>
            <p class="that">Overflow</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

/* create simple dom object from html */
$html = str_get_html($html_string);

/* find all paragraph elements */
$paragraph = $html->find('div[id=outer] div p');

/* loop through all elements and get inner text */
foreach($paragraph as $p){
    echo $p->innertext;
}
```

Cheers,

Roy

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$text = strip_tags($html);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

That will get you quite far. It leaves spaces and returns, but those are easy to remove.

```
$clean = str_replace(array(' ',"\n","\r"),'',$text);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Using it on your example gives:

```
TestPageHelloCommunityStackOverflow
```

If you want to leave some spaces intact you could instead try:

```
$clean = trim(implode('',explode("\n",$text)));
```

which results in:

```
Test Page Hello Community Stack Overflow
```

Many variations are possible.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are strongly not recommended to parse HTML.
Use Simple HTML library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simplehtmldom/
Include it: `include 'simple_html_dom.php';`
Get tags you need: `$tags = $html->find('p');`
Create array: `$a = array(); foreach ($tags as $tag) $a[] = $tag->innertext;`;
Create your string: `$string = $a[0] . $a[2] . $a[3] . $a[1];`

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname)
 {
    $pattern = "/<$tagname>(.*?)<\/$tagname>/";
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches[1];
 }
```

You have to loop through the $matches array...

Comment: @jurgemaister damn, beat me to it!