# PHP domDocument get a node contents (loading HTML)

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am trying to load a HTML document into a DOM object.
What I want is a list of all hyperlinks on that page.
I would love to know for each link what its properties are and what text it has.

I currently worked out a basic script that does all of that.. Except... the text.

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('test.html');

$dom            = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$Links         = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($Links as $node) {
    echo 'HREF = '.$node->getAttribute('href').PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Title = '.$node->getAttribute('title').PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Alt = '.$node->getAttribute('alt').PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Class = '.$node->getAttribute('class').PHP_EOL;
    echo 'ID = '.$node->getAttribute('id').PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Style = '.$node->getAttribute('style').PHP_EOL;
    echo 'Link text = '.$node->Data().PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

I have no clue how to get the text from the object.

So I want to know

```
<a href=somelink> **THIS TEXT IS WHAT I WANT TO SUBSTRACT**</a>
```

The line that currently does not work has :

```
echo 'Link text = '.$node->Data().PHP_EOL;
```

I hope that there is a function within the context that I am looking for.

> Just found the solution!
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> $html = file_get_contents('test.html');
>
> $dom          = new DOMDocument;
> @$dom->loadHTML($html);
> $Links         = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
>
> foreach ($Links as $node) {
>     echo 'HREF = '.$node->getAttribute('href').PHP_EOL;
>     echo 'Title = '.$node->getAttribute('title').PHP_EOL;
>     echo 'Alt = '.$node->getAttribute('alt').PHP_EOL;
>     echo 'Class = '.$node->getAttribute('class').PHP_EOL;
>     echo 'ID = '.$node->getAttribute('id').PHP_EOL;
>     echo 'Style = '.$node->getAttribute('style').PHP_EOL;
>     echo 'Link text = '.$node->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;
> }
>
> ?>
> ```
>
> Solution for this issue is :
>
> ```
> **echo 'Link text = '.$node->nodeValue.PHP_EOL;**
> ```
>
> *Or as I read... node->textContent should ALSO work*

@PoopNoodles... I found the solution on another site. But it might be interesting to know that there is another option as well. I do not know the difference between **nodeValue** and **textContent** though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php domdocument read element inner text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17054815/php-domdocument-read-element-inner-text) (use `->textContent`)

Comment: If you found a solution elsewhere on SO please delete the question.